# Why do we still use the 'P' subscript in a thermodynamic derivative such as (dH/dT)P?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

Consider the following thermodynamic derivative:

$$
\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial T}\right)_P
$$

Taking the partial derivative w.r.t. $T$ means that all other variables are held constant. Why do we still write it with a subscript like $P$ or $V$?

Comment: I made some pretty substantial edits to your post -- if I've misrepresented anything you wrote, or if you don't like anything I changed, please feel free to edit it back, or to roll back the edits entirely.

Comment: In particular, the use of MathJax in titles is discouraged (here on Chem.SE, at least), as it makes it hard to read search results on, e.g., Google.

Comment: Long story short, _all_ other variables **aren't and can't be** held constant.

Comment: Because we distinguish f(p,..) and f(V, ...) functions

Comment: its a maths thing not related to thermodynamics *per se*; if you want to differentiate a function of several variables  $f(x, y, z)$ wrt. *x* then then *y, z* need to be held constant, hence the curly $\partial$ to indicate a partial derivative and subscripts to indicate what is held constant, $(\partial f / \partial x)_{y,z}$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In thermodynamics, the number of degrees of freedom available to describe a system is given by [Gibbs' phase rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_rule):

$$
F = C - P + 2
$$

Here, $C$ is the number of components in the system, $P$ is the number of phases in the system, and $F$ is the number of resulting degrees of freedom.

Consider a pure substance in a closed system.  One can name a wide variety of thermodynamic parameters to describe its state: temperature, pressure, specific volume, internal energy, enthalpy, entropy, etc. However, Gibbs' phase rule says that we can only independently specify a subset of these parameters before we run out of degrees of freedom:

$$
F = 1 - 1 + 2 = 2
$$

So, in any mathematical description of (in your example) the enthalpy, $H$, it can only properly be a function of two independent variables:

$$
H = H\left(X_1, X_2\right)
$$

But: which two variables?

Simply writing the partial derivative $\partial H \over \partial T$ indicates that temperature is to be one of the two available degrees of freedom:

$$
H = H\left(T, X_2\right)
$$

Now, though – what is $X_2$? **Well, including the subscript on the differential is a way of explicitly indicating what that other independent variable is:**

$$
\left({\partial H \over \partial T}\right)_P \quad \Longrightarrow 
\quad H = H\left(T, P\right)
$$

As porphyrin rightly notes in a [comment](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/68676/why-do-we-still-use-the-p-subscript-in-a-thermodynamic-derivative-such-as-dh/68677#comment120567_68676), this applies to multivariate calculus generally, not just the calculus of thermodynamics.

Comment: Ok but what if something is a function of more than two variables ?

Comment: @mathemather For any given first derivative in any given system, if you have $F$ degrees of freedom, you should specify $F-1$ independent variables as subscripts to the derivative.

Answer (score 0):

It just means one is holding the experimental pressure constant when determining Cp.